Is there a way to move HTML between bowser tabs in Angular?
I am trying to build an Angular (v17) application which lets the user to move around with drag and drop HTML elements, even between multiple browser tabs. Similarly to what neo.mjs is capable of (here is a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L43hntj3jk).
I am currently using Material cdDrag, and thinking of writing a custom Angular shared web worker for this but it will be quite difficult if even possible.
Is there an easier way, or even a 3rd party package with which I could achieve this? Or could I somehow implement neo.mjs into my Angular application?
The project has to be Angular (client request).

I don't believe it's possible to achieve this via dragging/dropping, but you could potentially trigger the move from one tab to another by using a postMessage

It should be achiavable with https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview ( Angular Portals ) don't remember exactly how. watch this video it shows exactly how to do it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOPUvyrr3y4&t=889s

In this example I have a draggable <li> element and an iframe (the iframe is just to show that you can drag from one document to another). In the parent document, on dragstart I set data on the dataTransfer object to the HTML code being dragged (the <li> element). In the iframe there are handlers for both dragover and drop. When you drop the <li> the HTML will be added to the <ul> in the iframe. Below is the HTML for the iframe.
You can try to open the iframe document (the data URI string) in a separate tab, and test if you can drag the <li> from the example here to that tab.


document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.outerHTML);
});
body {
  display: flex;
}
<ul>
  <li draggable="true">Item 1</li>
  <li draggable="true">Item 2</li>
</ul>

<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,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"></iframe>



Iframe document:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('dragover', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  });

  document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('drop', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.innerHTML += e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  });
});
</script>
<style>
ul {min-height: 3em; border: thin dotted gray;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Drop zone:</div>
<ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>


Not exactly what i was looking for, but i was able to solve it with your answer, Thanks a lot!

would you pls share your answer

by using this third party package we are able to do drag and drop in between the tabs
  npm install interactjs

we could intiate the drag drop and dragend
interact.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import interact from 'interactjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InteractService {
  constructor() {}

  initDragDrop() {
    interact('.draggable')
      .draggable({
        onmove: this.dragMoveListener,
        onend: this.dragEndListener
      })
      .dropzone({
        accept: '.draggable',
        ondrop: this.dropListener
      });
  }

  dragMoveListener(event) {
    // Handle drag move
  }

  dragEndListener(event) {
    // Handle drag end
  }

  dropListener(event) {
    // Handle drop
  }
}

drag-drop.component.ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InteractService } from './interact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drag-drop',
  templateUrl: './drag-drop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drag-drop.component.css']
})
export class DragDropComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private interactService: InteractService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.interactService.initDragDrop();
  }
}


You could probably work up something by putting the zipped HTML in a cookie or in browser store on mousedown. Maybe you could even create a drag and drop UI using the page visibility API to read from that cookie when the other tab comes into focus.

Here is my very naive answer... I know that the native HTML 5 does support drag and drop across tabs/windows. So i did some very basic search and found this library ngx-drag-drop

Now for the demo:

Open their demo in one window tab. we will use this as the drop zone
Open another window with the same demo
Drag anything from #2 from any tab into the drop zone of #1
the content will be updated with the dropped item json

Hope this helps
